# Thermal Transfer with Heat Source

Tags: heat-transfer

Two objects (A & B) are separated by a 1 m long square rod (5 cm x 5 cm). The objects and rod have a thermal conductivity of 130 W/mK. Object A is a heat source of 10 W. Assume there is no convection cooling - only conduction down the rod and radiative cooling (black body surfaces). 20 C ambient temperature.

What is the temperature of object A (heat source)?
What is the temperature of object B?

I can use Fourier's Law to find the heat convection but get stuck trying to find the temperature of the heat source object.

Comment: The heat equation. You will need to understand PDEs. At 5x5cm, 10W and 20C, I would neglect transfer to the air to make things a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks @DKNguyen I tried to use k / (density * Cp) + d2T/dx2 + q_v / (density * Cp) = 0, which rearranges to d2T(x)/dx2 = - q_v / k. Integrating both sides gives dT(x)/dx = - q_v * x / k + C1, Integrating both sides again gives T(x) = - (q_v * x^2) / (2 * k) + (C1 * x) + C2. If body A temp is T1, body B temp is T2 and L is the length of the rod, using boundary conditions of T(x=0) = T1 = C2 and T(x=L) = T2 = - (q_v * L^2) / (2 * k) + C1 * x + T1, then rearranging to find C1 gives C1 = (q_v * L) / (2 * k) + (T2 - T1) / L.  ... Continuing in next comment...

Comment: So the solve equation is T(x) = - (q_v * x^2) / (2 * k) + (q_v * L * x) / (2 * k) + ((T2 - T1) * x) / L + T1.  Not sure if the above is correct and unsure how that then tells me the temperature of objects A and B?

Comment: Also this doesn't take into account the cooling from radiation, which is Q_rad = sigma * A (T_surface^4 - T_amb^4), but I unsure am how to include it within the heat equation apart from the fact Q_in should equal Q_out.

Comment: It would be better if you added the equations to the question as edit. Other people can then help you with Tex notation if needed or other improvements (comments can't be edited after a while).